# Creating a simple self-signed crlertificate with openssl x509/ca/req

Tags: openssl

All I want to do is create a self-signed certificate that is like this:

- It has the serial number of `0`.
- It lacks both a start date and end date.

  - If this cannot be done using OpenSSL, then I'd like to have the start date be `00000101000000Z` and the end date `99991231235959Z`.
  - If this can be done using other tools in conjunction with OpenSSL, then let me know.
- SHA-256 is the hash algorithm.
- With no default values used if I choose to leave a field blank. So, I don't want to see `Widgets, Inc.` in the organization name field if I choose not to fill it out when I am prompted.

The problem with using `openssl x509` is that it does not allow me to specify the start date, the end date, or the serial number.

`openssl ca` allows me to set the start and end dates as command line parameters, but using this command requires that I have a configuration file, a particular directory structure, and I cannot choose the serial number I want to use as a command line parameter. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7768593/openssl-as-a-ca-without-touching-the-certs-crl-index-etc-environment) has the same complaint. I don't want to use special directories NOR do I want to specify the configuration ib an environment variable. Do not ask me why I want to do it this way.

`openssl req` seemed like what I needed until I realized that it uses the same sort of configuration as `openssl ca`.

Comment: `x509 -req` and `req -x509` both allow serial as (commandline) option, but start not at all and end not the way you want. `ca` and `req` do require a config file and `ca` two others, but neither requires any particular directory structure. (Although the last system I know that could have files without _any_ directory was OS/360.) So you can't do it with commandline. A program you write that calls the library can do it, if you count that as an 'other tool'.

Comment: Dave, regarding your comment. "ca and req do require a config file and ca two others" - what do you mean by "and ca two others"?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand you looking for something like:

configuration file: openssl.cfg

```
# use 'ca' as the default section because we're usign the ca command
[ ca ]
default_ca = custom_ca

[ custom_ca ]
dir             = ./demoCA
serial          = $dir/serial     #  a text file containing the next serial number to use in hex. Mandatory.
                                 #  This file must be present and contain a valid serial number.

database        = $dir/index.txt # the text database file to use. Mandatory. This file must be present though
new_certs_dir   = $dir/newcerts  # specifies the directory where new certificates will be placed. Mandatory.
certificate     = ./ca.crt       # the file containing the CA certificate. Mandatory
private_key     = ./ca.key       # the file contaning the CA private key. Mandatory
default_days    = 365            # how long to certify for
default_md      = sha256         # the message digest algorithm. Remember to not use MD5
policy          = custom_policy  # a section with a set of variables corresponding to DN fields


[ custom_policy ]
# if the value is "match" then the field value must match the same field in the
# CA certificate. If the value is "supplied" then it must be present.
# Optional means it may be present. Any fields not mentioned are silently
# deleted.
countryName         = match     # C
stateOrProvinceName = match     # ST
localityName        = match     # L
```

-

```
$ openssl req -nodes -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout ca.key -out ca.csr -subj "/C=US/ST=California/L=Los Angeles"
$ openssl x509 -req -days 365 -in ca.csr -signkey ca.key -out ca.crt
$ openssl req -nodes -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout new_server.key -out new_server.csr -subj "/C=US/ST=California/L=Los Angeles"

$ mkdir ./demoCA
$ mkdir ./demoCA/newcerts
$ > ./demoCA/index.txt
$ echo 00 > ./demoCA/serial

$ openssl ca -config ./openssl.cfg -out new_server.crt -startdate 00000101000000Z -enddate 99991231235959Z -cert ca.crt -keyfile ca.key -infiles new_server.csr
```

If you have a `segmentation fault 11`, you need to change the `index.txt.attr` from `unique_subject = yes` to `unique_subject = no`:

```
$ cat demoCA/index.txt.attr
unique_subject = no


$ openssl req -text -noout -in ca.csr 
Certificate Request:
    Data:
        Version: 0 (0x0)
        Subject: C=US, ST=California, L=Los Angeles
        Subject Public Key Info:
            Public Key Algorithm: rsaEncryption
                Public-Key: (2048 bit)
                Modulus:
                    00:a8:d7:f8:b3:3c:66:7d:ca:2d:fc:05:ea:93:2b:
                    ee:db:a8:f3:69:fd:6a:7a:6b:4f:52:ae:5c:ba:46:
                    dc:72:35:58:17:48:59:60:76:72:db:5f:ba:50:d7:
                    05:6b:45:b5:84:27:05:b0:86:7a:41:ff:04:32:14:
                    1e:73:1a:78:b4:36:95:e4:dd:04:73:47:ae:19:e9:
                    ed:0c:f7:52:a7:8a:1e:43:96:86:a4:59:d0:51:9b:
                    a9:50:19:38:e0:ff:cd:f8:ed:6c:76:ef:6f:fc:33:
                    33:16:15:d5:27:31:15:6f:c0:b7:9e:2f:22:fa:77:
                    d7:d6:06:a8:51:87:b9:7f:c3:35:0e:33:f5:04:a8:
                    d2:f5:5a:29:c4:1f:e9:db:d0:7e:e7:d0:a2:fc:8e:
                    c7:8b:5a:ca:b5:7d:c1:29:e9:6d:c1:20:01:6f:68:
                    d9:06:27:87:7b:fc:02:e7:4a:d9:32:5d:6b:18:0b:
                    c6:57:b7:06:c8:b9:08:b6:bc:c4:52:76:c3:b8:58:
                    49:9f:46:ca:ef:96:17:88:3c:6a:cf:a9:a9:51:2e:
                    ff:a9:20:52:d0:6b:0e:1c:c9:20:46:3c:28:d5:1d:
                    1d:c0:46:15:18:a6:6a:4d:ec:02:44:7e:78:f7:47:
                    ff:49:49:77:1d:15:c6:6d:07:a2:74:c6:fc:70:2a:
                    d6:e9
                Exponent: 65537 (0x10001)
        Attributes:
            a0:00
    Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
         58:fb:28:e1:99:d0:b5:7b:5d:3d:16:e9:ab:f2:b2:9f:e9:28:
         0f:a0:65:ab:ea:00:69:4b:44:1c:2f:1e:aa:38:60:2a:19:16:
         12:19:5c:67:83:5f:fe:21:d9:eb:dd:cb:ec:be:af:d5:5a:31:
         05:99:73:9a:1f:8e:39:0f:1a:7e:68:7f:d0:ad:6f:76:8f:d2:
         83:e0:bf:27:a2:5c:c2:ca:09:33:e2:88:56:ac:4e:5b:51:58:
         62:d2:57:71:49:02:5b:bd:09:08:a8:fc:70:05:19:f2:8d:b9:
         86:19:4a:d6:53:51:f7:6c:c3:dd:c7:50:24:b0:20:5d:07:3d:
         6a:e0:60:d1:d0:4b:ab:a0:ad:ab:c6:62:5a:a8:79:4d:d9:f0:
         46:a7:27:c5:e1:62:2d:a7:88:2f:30:a4:8b:a6:05:c9:d1:af:
         09:c6:db:08:48:d7:72:4a:89:c9:09:15:de:31:8a:97:17:ea:
         45:0e:f1:c5:a0:25:fe:a1:df:fb:35:6a:b0:56:a3:f6:fe:ae:
         1b:fb:64:9c:95:43:bf:73:26:17:b0:5e:23:2c:9e:45:2f:05:
         3d:0e:6d:32:3b:80:f4:a1:80:6e:fd:15:3d:ad:21:4d:4e:87:
         da:74:c6:48:55:e4:03:5e:3e:9c:c7:ac:c2:40:3e:3f:b0:df:
         9b:59:a1:12
```